# Tailwind CSS Card Not going under the navbar

Tags: tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-6

The card is not going under the navbar, however, the navbar is fixed.

[image]

Code for card:

```
<div class="w-full flex justify-center no-wrap">
    <div class="bg-white p-8 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative hover:shadow-2xl transition duration-500">
      <h1 class="text-sm text-gray-400 font-semibold mb-1"><%= @question.question_asked_on %>.</h1>
      <h1 class="text-2xl text-gray-800 font-semibold mb-3"><%= @question.title %>.</h1>
      <div class="w-full">
        <p class="text-gray-600 leading-6 tracking-normal">
          <%= @question.body %>
        </p>
      </div>

      <button class="py-2 px-4 mt-8 bg-indigo-600 text-white rounded-md shadow-xl">Learn  More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code for navbar

```
<nav class="bg-indigo-700 fixed inset-x-0">
  <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4">
    <div class="flex justify-between">
      <div class="flex space-x-7">
        <div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) in order to be able to try the code?

Answer (score 1):

if you remove `relative` from the card it should go under the navbar.